How to optimize the intersection between two triangular meshes?
I am trying to intersect two surface meshes, named slope and slide, and then combine the two into a coherent triangular mesh.  The two meshes are shown follows:

(part of Slide is below Slope, and thus they will intersect each other)

By using CGAL::split function I was able to get the intersected nodes:

When you zoom in, you will find the intersected nodes form triangulars in a bad shape:

and here comes my question: how can I filter the intersected nodes so that nodes number will reduce while still (almost) keep the boundary shape, like the 3rd image shown below:

Now I am able to get a vertex and its associated halfedges, and reset these halfedges to another vertex, but I do not know what strategy I can use.
May I know if there exists a strategy that can handle this ? I will be grateful if anyone help this. Thank you.
I use CGAL::split method to intersect the two meshes, and I want to reshape the intersections between the two meshes so that it will form a good triangular shape

I think the answer is a research paper by itself.

What I'd do is first work out a way to identify "bad shape".  We can restrict such identification to the nodes near the intersection, so we don't mess with other parts of the mesh.
A simple first heuristic could just be "small triangles" (in area), which is easy to calculate (a simple cross product and magnitude).
Then implement methods to fix or remove a "bad shape".  A really obvious one to me would be to literally collapse a triangle; we take a corner vertex and we move it over to its closest other corner vertex, moving every other triangle connected to that vertex as well.  Triangles converted into lines are eliminated.
Then see how much we changed the shape of the mesh by doing this.
Repeat until you either have no "bad shapes", or elimination of every "bad shape" causes too much change in the overall mesh shape.
This will probably take sharp corners at the intersection and make them "duller"; fixing that is a bit trickier; you'd want to identify the "seam" and keep it around with high fidelity.
